# Docker mounted volume only updates on container restart

Tags: node.js, docker, aurelia

I have a docker container which has NodeJs, npm, jspm & aurelia implemented, my src folder containing the styles, assets, html and js files in mounted on the host file system.

Everything looks fine but when I update html or js in the mounted volume and refresh the web app the changes are not reflected.

My docker file is as follows;

```
   FROM node:6.1.0
   MAINTAINER   Webnostix code@webnostix.co.uk

   RUN npm install -g jspm
   RUN apt-get -y install git
   RUN npm install aurelia-cli -g
   RUN npm install gulp -g

   # Setup the script to run on startup
   COPY . /var/www/

   EXPOSE 9000 3001
   WORKDIR /var/www/
   CMD npm install -y && au run —watch
```

I am running the docker container with the following command from my host directory containing my source code

```
    docker run -it --name AureliaBoilerPlate -v $(pwd):/var/www/src -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 webgnostics/aurelia
```

Everything runs ok and I can see my web app on the correct port etc.. however code changes made in my local directory only update upon restarting the docker container, which is not what I understand to be how it's supposed to work.

Any ideas??

Comment: Which text editor are you using to edit your code?

Comment: Hi Jose, I have tried using VSC as well as in Nano as I heard about the way the unix/linux saves files, do you think this would also apply to nano?

Comment: It should work if you're using nano.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's an Aurelia thing?? perhaps I should test the docker functionality with a simple Node js app, not sure..

Comment: I'm calling au (Aurelia) run -watch from the /var/www/ directory on the container maybe it's not watching the mounted ***src*** file which would be mounted into ***/var/www/*** for some reason - not sure how to fix that if it's the issue

Comment: What platform are you running on? If (for example) you're running Docker inside a VirtualBox VM, inotify does not work, so your package won't get notified of changes in the filesystem. In that case you need to use "polling"

Comment: In Dockerfile you are copying `.` into `/var/www` but in the `run` command you are mounting `.` into `/var/www/src` - is that intentional? Maybe you want to mount it to `/var/www` as well?

Comment: I'm using Docker 17.03.1 Community edition which I don't believe uses VM's

Comment: @LukášDoležal , Im copying my whole project to /var/www/ this copies my framework plus nodemodules and the project code (the src folder). I am then mounting a src folder from my host OS (that's where I'm editing code) essentially overwriting the src folder on the guest container. does that sound correct to you?

Comment: @LukášDoležal - I noticed that even though I copied a whole broject into the container during the build, when it mounts it only contains a single file - any ideas why?

Comment: @LukášDoležal When I created a snapshot and browsed the src folder all the files were present they had just not been mounted to the host filesystem - any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: How and in which folder do you run `docker build`? Do you run it in your www folder? Or pass it the folder as context?

Comment: @LukášDoležal - Thanks for you help with this, however I now realise that I was misunderstanding the volume mount concept in docker. I was expecting a folder inside the container to be mounted externally where in reality you mount your local folder onto the container essentially extending the functionality of the container to your host machine.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to let `au run --watch` run detached using docker-compose. Having that detached a `au build` refreshs the application as well. Maybe better than restarting the total container everytime.

Getting the application refreshed by code changes currently doesn't work (as far as I know). Also see this discussion here: [Github](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/787)

Following my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  aurelia-cli-runner:
    image: saschan/aurelia-cli:latest
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/local/etc/app
    working_dir: //usr/local/etc/app
    command: "au run --watch"
```

Starting the container detached:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

Refreshing the application: `au build`

Hope, that it helps.